# How to fetch array or json objects using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am using the MERN stack and am a beginner. I have my express app running on port 3001 and this is my dbconn route. It successfully pulls the query and if I navigate to "localhost:3001/dbconn" it shows the docs array.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const uri ='mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@wager0-mhodf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  //Connect to db
  client.connect(err => {
      console.log("Connected successfully to server");
      //navigate to correction
      const collection = client.db("wager0").collection("gameTypes");
      //Get all rows in db
      collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        res.send(docs);
      });
      
    client.close();
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However when I try to fetch this array in my react app, it simply is pulling an empty array. Below is the code for my Test component which is then rendered in my app.js file in the client(react) application. What I really need to do is create a dropdown list with all available gametypes, but will settle for just being able to fetch the array.

```js
// Dependencies 
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {gameTypes: []};
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/dbconn', {
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res =>  this.setState({gameTypes: res}));
        console.log(this.state.gameTypes);    
    }

    render (){
        return( 
            <div className="GameTypes">
                <h1>Game Types</h1>
                <div>
                    <select>
                        <option>test</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Your fetch happens asynchronously, so you shouldn't expect your state to be set in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. If you want to see your state being updated, log the state in the `componentDidUpdate` hook: `componentDidUpdate(){ console.log(this.state.gameTypes) }`

Comment: Nick, I need to fetch the array upon mounting the component. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You where almost close. Just console log inside the promise resolve and use the state inside your template. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { gameTypes: [] };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/dbconn', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({ gameTypes: res });
      console.log(this.state.gameTypes);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="GameTypes">
        <h1>Game Types</h1>
        <div>
          <select>
            {this.state.gameTypes.map(gameType => (
              <option>{gameType.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: I've noticed that my dbconn file will load the data into an array upon starting the server and navigating to the route, but any subsequent visit pull an empty array. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Dependencies 
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Test extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {gameTypes: []};
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/dbconn', {
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(data =>  this.setState({gameTypes: data}));
        console.log(this.state.gameTypes);    
    }

    render (){
        return( 
            <div className="GameTypes">
                <h1>Game Types</h1>
                <div>
                    <select>
                        <option>test</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Change your code with above snippet. While using fetch api in react you need to convert response to JSON first and again need to write .then function. In second .then function you will get your data.

Don't use console.log() to check state value after setState() because react's setState method is asynchronous.

Comment: Should I use a state variable to store this kind of data? I read that state variables should not hold objects, and should be kept simple. I am pulling this data to create a dynamic dropdown for a form. Would you suggest taking a different approach?

Comment: State variable can hold object and there i nothing wrong in it. just remember javascript object is a reference type so do take care while manipulating it.